# Disabling button until UITableView is loaded with data from Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, uibutton

I am working on a little App with parse.com. The App will load data from Parse.com and display it to a UITableView. I also have a second ViewController with a Button. If I click on this button, it will display the TableViewController.
My Problem is: The tableView takes a while to load all data from parse.com. How can I set a "wait" or "stop" for the Button on the ViewController until tableview is loaded complete? 
I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [PFQueryTableViewController](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html) and override the method [objectsDidLoad](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/objectsDidLoad:) to enable/change your button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the data into the TableViewController on `viewDidLoad`, then your ViewController has to open the table in order to trigger that event.

A more common way to handle this situation would be like this:

1. Don't do anything to your button. Let it open the TableViewController whenever it wants.
2. When the TableViewController loads, show an activity/loading indicator while you wait for your Parse data to show up.
3. Once your Parse query completes, hide the activity indicator and show the data.

If you'd rather make the button enabled only when the data is ready, then you will need to query the Parse data in your ViewController and pass it to the TableViewController (like in `prepareForSegue`).